Problema al hacer commit en unos archivos HTML
Estoy guardando los cambios en los archivos de la rama dev, al agregarlos con git add . en la terminal de git me dice lo siguiente:
warning: in the working copy of 'Estructura/Estructura_De_Contenido.html', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'Estructura/Etiquetas_Para_Textos.html', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'Estructura/Introduccion.html', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it

Pero al ejecutar git status, me muestra los archivos listos para comitear, pero al hacer el commit me muestra esto otro:
error: invalid object 100644 b699502d92f9810e40b47a672a9fb343bcea144b for 'Estructura/Enlaces.html'
error: invalid object 100644 b699502d92f9810e40b47a672a9fb343bcea144b for 'Estructura/Enlaces.html'
error: Error building trees

Lo único que le hice a los archivos fue una refactorización, pero no sé por que me manda ese error
